# Unable to turn some broken links into qualified ones

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I'm trying to create a script in vba which will look for any `contact` or `contact us` link within ***any given website*** in order to come up with a qualified /usable link. My current script does parse the contact link but most of the times they are not qualified to be reused later, meaning broken ones.

I've tried so far:

```
Sub FetchCustomizedLink()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim link As Variant, links As Variant, targetlink$

    links = Array( _
        "http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/", _
        "https://www.plexure.com.sg/", _
        "http://www.mount-zion.biz/", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/" _
    )

    For Each link In links
        targetlink = None

        With Http
            .Open "GET", link, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            On Error Resume Next
            .send
            On Error GoTo 0
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("a[href]")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                If InStr(1, .item(I).innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then
                    targetlink = .item(I).getAttribute("href")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next I
        End With
        Debug.Print targetlink
    Next link
End Sub
```

Output I'm getting:

```
about:/contact.html
https://www.plexure.com.sg/contact
about:contactus.html
https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact
```

Output I wish to get:

```
http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/contact.html
https://www.plexure.com.sg/contact
http://www.mount-zion.biz/contactus.html
https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact
```

***How can I turn the broken links into qualified ones?***

Comment: Make an assumption and take the base domain from the initial request url? i.e. everything before the third / ? Also, you would need a Select case you extend to handle the text in the actual href you extract which needs replacing e.g. *about:*

Comment: Nice to find you in the loop @QHarr. Yes, `select case` might be the ideal way to go. I've tried with `Like` operator but it seems to be way more complex to handle multiple type of patterns. What you thought is right by the way.

Comment: Hi - could you replace either `about:/` or `about:` with an item with the link array?

Comment: I don't mind going through any route as long as the output are similar to the expected ones.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've done it. I had to use `InStr()` function within `Left()` function to single out the base url and then make use of `Replace()` function along with `Like` operator to build the qualified `contact` links.

```
Sub FetchCustomizedLink()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim link As Variant, links As Variant, targetlink$
    Dim base$, refinedportion$, refinedlink$

    links = Array( _
        "http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/", _
        "https://www.plexure.com.sg/", _
        "http://www.mount-zion.biz/", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/", _
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/" _
    )

    For Each link In links
        targetlink = None

        With Http
            .Open "GET", link, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            On Error Resume Next
            .send
            On Error GoTo 0
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("a[href]")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                If InStr(1, .item(I).innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then
                    targetlink = .item(I).getAttribute("href")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next I
        End With

        If InStr(link, "http:") > 0 Then
            base = Left(link, InStr(8, link, "/") - 1)
        ElseIf InStr(link, "https:") > 0 Then
            base = Left(link, InStr(9, link, "/") - 1)
        End If

        refinedportion = Replace(targetlink, "about:", "")

        If refinedportion Like "[/]*" Then
            refinedlink = base & refinedportion
        ElseIf refinedportion Like "[h]*" Then
            refinedlink = refinedportion
        Else
            refinedlink = base & "/" & refinedportion
        End If
        Debug.Print refinedlink
    Next link
End Sub
```

What it produces:

```
http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/contact.html
https://www.plexure.com.sg/contact
http://www.mount-zion.biz/contactus.html
https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact
https://www.yellowpages.com/about/contact-us
```